# SQL Server Maintenance Plans fail to execute after installing SSDT

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a P.C with Visual Studio 2015 Professional and SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.3 installed on it. I would like to develop SSIS & SSRS projects so installed SSDT version 14.0.60413.0, which has been the suggested download for SQL Server SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.3. However, after the installation of SSDT the maintenance plans for the database fail to execute.

Message

> Executed as user:
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
>   Version 13.0.1000.281 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (c) 2015 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  12:44:25 PM
>   Error: 2016-06-13 12:44:25.62
>   Code: 0xC0010018
>
> Source:
>   Description: Error loading value "
>
> Could not load package "Maintenance Plans\TransactionLogs" because of error 0xC0010014.  Description: One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.
>
> Source:
>   Started:  12:44:25 PM
>   Finished: 12:44:25 PM
>   Elapsed:   0.141 seconds.
>   The package could not be loaded. The step failed.

The maintenance plans begin to work when restoring the system to a point before the installation of SSDT. Has anyone experienced anything similar? I would appreciate any assistance as would like to begin developing SSIS projects without interrupting the maintenance plans.

Comment: does a fresh generated maintenance plan expose the same error?

Comment: Hi thst, thanks for your post. Yes, unfortunately a newly generated maintenance plan gets the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the maintenance plan as an SSIS package in the file system, and execute it from there?  Ideally, I would try that *first* from a pre-SSDT-installation condition, and if it works, install SSDT and try again executing it from the file system.

Why I bring this up:  because SSIS packages can be stored using the package deployment model, or the project deployment model, and I wondered if the SSDT install was affecting where it expects the packages to be.  Storing a package in the file system (as a `.DTSX`) would avoid that issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Hi,
1.  Check pre-requites configuration
2.  Check whether Supporting Service pack is properly installed
3.  Make sure that the package is executed with correct DTEXEC
4.  Make sure Sql server installed runs on 32 bit
5.  Make sure that project properties –debugging – setting Run64BitRuntime is set to false
"